# Image is null [NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key:)

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

i have this game app a cocos2d which i downloaded it is an open source game...

i am trying to insert an online leaderboard to it using gamecenter. however

the image that i insert seems to be crashing the game.

i have inserted it here:

```
    MenuItem *button1 = [MenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"playAgainButton.png" selectedImage:@"playAgainButton.png" target:self selector:@selector(button1Callback:)];
    MenuItem *button2 = [MenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"changePlayerButton.png" selectedImage:@"changePlayerButton.png" target:self selector:@selector(button2Callback:)];
    MenuItem *button3 = [MenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"blank1.png" selectedImage:@"blank1.png" target:self selector:@selector(button3Callback:)];

    Menu *menu = [Menu menuWithItems: button1, button2, button3, nil];

    [menu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:9];
    menu.position = ccp(160,48);

    [self addChild:menu];

    return self;
}
```

the

```
MenuItem *button3 = [MenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"blank1.png" selectedImage:@"blank1.png" target:self selector:@selector(button3Callback:)];
```

thats the one then i edited the button3callback like this :

```
-(void)button3Callback:(id)sender
{
    GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardRequest != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"leaderboardrequest is not equal nil");
        leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
        leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(1,10);
        [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil)
            {
                // handle the error.
                NSLog(@"ERROR : %@",[error localizedDescription]);
            }
            if (scores != nil)
            {
                // process the score information.

                for (id thisScore in scores) {
                    NSLog(@"Score %@  ", thisScore);
                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Scores == nil");
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

now i am having this errors :

```
2011-12-20 11:29:40.984 tweejump[2936:707] Image is Null
2011-12-20 11:29:40.988 tweejump[2936:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: blank1.png)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31cca8bf 0x31a3a1e5 0x31cca7b9 0x31cca7db 0x31c376bb 0x35dc9 0x2f63f 0x2f5c5 0x25385 0x252f9 0x2522f 0x43cc7 0x429bb 0x4235f 0x2e95f 0x2f515 0xf26f 0x358db61d 0x31c9ea63 0x31c9e6c9 0x31c9d29f 0x31c204dd 0x31c203a5 0x31d2cfed 0x327b0743 0x2873 0x282c)
```

i make it sure that the image is in its proper place... and i dont know why it is nil?

i have tried on both sim and real device and i have the same errors.

what else should i do ?

Comment: Do you make sure you have no mis-spelling about name of image ? Ex: @"blank1.png" v.s. @"BLANK1.PNG" in filesystem.

Comment: are you keeping playAgainButton & changePlayerButton in a different place than `blank1.png`?  if you create a `UIImage` with `blank1.png` (just to see if it creates), is it NULL or is it not null?  I.E. let's try to isolate where the problem really is.

Comment: @Toro - nope i have both @"blank1.png"

**Michael Dautermann** - it is the same with play again and change player..  what i see about the 3 is that both changeplayer and play again are "Alpha Channel :YES" and blank1 is no

Comment: dont you think the `alignitemsverticallywithpadding` and `menu position` affects it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the Answer**

i have inserted an image that is not a real png file...

thats why it says that the image is null because it couldn't find a real png file

i have replaced it with a real png image and now it works well ..

thanks to all who replied :)